# How to reset system proxy in CentOS 6 using python code

Tags: python, proxy

I am using the following python code (Python 2.7) to reset the proxy of my (Cent OS 6) system, but I am unable to reset the proxy:

Code:

```
 import os 
 print "Unsetting http..." 
 os.system("unset http_proxy") 
 os.system("echo $http_proxy") 
 print "http is reset"
```

Output:

```
Unsetting http...
http://web-proxy.xxxx.xxxxxxx.net:8080
http is reset
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It should not return http://web-proxy.xxxx.xxxxxxx.net:8080 in output.

I run the same unset command from the terminal, then I see that proxy is reset:

[trex@sumlnxvm ~]$ unset $HTTP_PROXY
[trex@sumlnxvm ~]$ echo $HTTP_PROXY

[trex@sumlnxvm ~]$ 
Please suggest how to reset system proxy using Python Code

Comment: CentOS is not Ubuntu. It's not even based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it. The environment variable starts off with your parent shell (the one you ran your program from). The parent shell creates a new process (to run your Python code in), and copies the environment variables to that process. Each of your `os.system()` creates a new process, and copies the environment variables to it. Then, the `os.system()` created process exits, and its environment goes away.

Child processes cannot change the environment of the parent.